# Why is my $routeprovider empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, route-provider

I have a question about the $routeProvider. In my code I have a $routeProvider.

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/language/:countryCode', routing)
        .when('/promotion/:promotionCode', routing)
        .otherwise(routing);
}]);
```

the 'routing' variable directs to a controller called registrationController. There, I have this initialise method.

```
$scope.initialise = function () {       
    console.log($routeParams);
}
```

When I go to my browser and type in the URL:

*mydomain/registration#/promotion/:free*

The console prints out

```
Object {promotionCode: ":free"}
```

But now when I change that same URL to

*mydomain/registration#/language/:US-EN*

The console prints out and empty object.

Does anyone know why, even though the routing is exactly the same, it doesn't recognize the language route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I gave in the question itself was correct. I forgot to compile and build the project. I wasn't aware that needed to be done for javascript changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the ":". The ":" is for creation of url query

Comment: Do you mean the ":" in the URL or in the routeProvider itself?

Comment: Tried both but didn't work. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

may be change your routProvider config. and add case sensitivity.

```
   $routeProvider
    .when('/language/:countryCode',{templateUrl: 'your template',controller:langCtrl,caseInsensitiveMatch: truel}
   )
     .when('/promotion/:promotionCode', routing)
     .otherwise(routing);
    }]);
```